# Passing a Typescript class to a SharedWorker to create the worker

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

When creating SharedWorkers you would pass the JS file inside the SharedWorker constructor such as

```
var worker = new SharedWorker('some_worker_file.js');
```

That file will contain a line that gets executed right away as its not inside any function. That line would be something like -

```
this.addEventlistener('connect', function(e) { ... handler code ... } );
```

Now how do you do something similar with Typescript?  You aren't calling new XXX so placing the code inside a constructor is pointless.
What's the best way to create a class with Typescript to do this - is it possible?

I'm wondering if the only way to do this is to create a simple JS file with the connect listener to set up the worker and also have that simple JS file load in the transpiled TS files as imports.

Comment: what's the reason for using a typescript class? what's wrong with just writing that method call?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using simple loading of JS - but I'm experimenting with TS and seeing what it can and can't do.

I'd like every file in a Typescript project to be a TS file. Full types, classes etc.

Comment: Types sure, but there's no hard requirement to have a class. Your code is already going to be run in a worker.. I'd say that's modularized enough. :)

Comment: The worker will end up being a complex piece of code (bit like a separate app) so I'd like to get its base to be a TS class.  But I think I'm going to have to create a JS entry point file that gets loaded first.